# Is there anything for asking the most questions for a specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, privileges

From *what I can see, there is something that allows a user to single handedly close that topics questions.

So is there something similar for someone who has asked the most questions on that tag?

Comment: No.....there isn't.

Comment: Are you asking if there’s a power similar to that granted by a gold tag badge for users who ask a great number of questions in a certain tag?

Comment: @Paulie_D, damm it!!!

Comment: @Adamant, I am not sure. What do you mean?

Comment: Not sure why there would be a need. SE is about rewarding **answers** more than questions.

Comment: @Paulie_D, bad ieda. No questions, no answers.

Comment: You can find all the badges here - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Comment: ..and it's about **quality** not *quantity*.

Comment: @Paulie_D, still, if there are no questions, there will be no answers. Sort of like cutting off your nose to spite the face...

Comment: ...again, **quality** is what counts.

Comment: Since asking lots of questions about a specific topic doesn't imply knowledge about that topic (if anything, it tends to correlate with a *lack* of knowledge), **no, you don't get any tag-specific rewards or powers for asking many questions in that tag.** See [this main meta feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71603/278659); the closest thing to an implementation of this idea has been [the Curious/Inquisitive/Socratic badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/278659). You can also see a **list of top askers in any tag**, as b_jonas mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @Adamant I've updated my answer with a table.

Comment: I do agree with your "no questions, no answers" point though, and even once [wrote a poem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=22415315#22415315) to that effect. This is why I make a point of posting questions regularly, especially about less popular SF/F works.

Comment: You get the warm sense of satisfaction in a job well done.

Answer (score 8):

### There’s not

**Gold tag badges (or indeed all tag badges) only take into account *answers***, not questions. There aren’t any closing powers that users can acquire (at the moment) from asking a great number of questions in a certain tag, even if those questions receive lots of upvotes.

Of course, asking lots of questions *does* give one more generic privileges on the site, through reputation—but nothing tag-based.

There’s a good reason for this: the gold tag badge powers are not merely a reward for answering a bunch of questions, but are given to people who *understand* a topic well enough to know when questions are duplicates. Giving lots of well-received answers is a better metric of that than asking lots of well-received questions. After all, many well-received questions are asked by people without much knowledge of the topic at all: **they’re just good questions.**  Indeed, asking a large number of questions in an area *might*, on average, indicate a great deal of curiosity about the area but not in-depth knowledge (though, if this does hold, it is **certainly** not true in all cases). Further, the badge is also a sign that you’ve seen a lot of posts that might be duplicates.

You *can* get a number of excellent gold badges for asking questions (though again, nothing tag-based).

- There are [Great Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/great-question) badges, obviously. These are fairly hard to get and reward the best questions.
- The [Socratic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/124/socratic) badge rewards people who ask good questions consistently over a long period of time.
- The [Famous Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question) badge rewards people whose questions bring users to our site.

Comment: But, then those people with all these question will become more knowledgeable in that area, no?

Comment: @KyloRen - Sure, but it’s not as strong a sign of knowledge as lots of good answers.

Comment: Yes, I can conceed that. But after a ceratin amount of Q's , suerly that person should know a lot more about the topic. BTW, how do you get a badge like you mention?

Comment: @KyloRen - Like what?

Comment: Like Valorium's starwars privlage. He can close a question releated to startwars by him self.

Comment: @KyloRen - Answer 200 questions with a minimum score (upvotes - downvotes) of 1000 total.

Comment: Thats a lot of questions.

Comment: @KyloRen - It is. I have [tag:harry-potter]. My next closest is [tag:story-identification], but that’s a long way away. Such things take longer than most gold badges (with the exception of Steward, Illuminator, and perhaps Legendary, I suppose).

Comment: Nice! !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @KyloRen: I'd like to note that gold tag badges can be awarded only if you give at least 200 answers, and Sci Fi SE has only two users here who have ever given at least 200 questions in a given tag, and those users have a gold tag badge anyway.

Comment: @b_jonas, who is that?

Comment: @KyloRen: see in my answer.

Comment: @b_jonas, no deadpool

Comment: @KyloRen gold tag badges are rock hard to get. It's not so much the overall score, it's the sheer number of answers it takes

Answer (score 7):

The former are called gold tag badges.  You can see all the gold tag badges awarded [on the main site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) , and [on the meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold).

For asking a lot of questions about a topic, there isn't a specific award.  However, there is an easy way to find out who has asked high reputation questions about a tag.  On a tag page, eg. [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), follow the "top users" link to go to a page like [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/harry-potter%20/topusers).That page contains a list under the heading *"Top [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) Askers: All Time"* which shows that [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/slytherincess) has asked questions in this tag for a total score of 3891 (score means the difference of upvotes and downvotes on a post).  The list is sorted by the total score, not the number of posts.

**Update.**  For reference, here are the users who have posted the highest number of questions in each tag.

This is based on the data dump from 2016-09, so it's not completely up to date.  It counts all questions, including tag wiki ones and closed ones, but not deleted questions, and it doesn't care about the score.  The number of questions in that tag is shown before each user.  Only users who have asked 24 or more questions are shown, and only for tags with 100 or more questions.

- [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)

  - 71 [FuzzyBoots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23243)
  - 27 [Major Stackings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4356)
  - 25 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
- [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)

  - 236 [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500)
  - 217 [DVK-in-exile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976)
  - 91 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 68 [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693)
  - 55 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
  - 53 [CHEESE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51142)
  - 47 [vap78](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40429)
  - 45 [Jake](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/36050)
  - 41 [ibid](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/55866)
  - 40 [user13267](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13716)
  - 38 [b_jonas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4918)
  - 38 [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394)
  - 34 [Kevin The Knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/26703)
  - 30 [forgivemymoccasins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/8199)
  - 30 [Anoplexian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/60197)
  - 30 [Major Stackings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4356)
  - 28 [The Dark Lord](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/64888)
  - 28 [Mooz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267)
  - 26 [Xantec](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1234)
  - 26 [Himarm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/29220)
  - 26 [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148)
  - 25 [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43655)
  - 25 [prakhar londhe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54738)
  - 25 [bleh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57642)
  - 24 [Axelonet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48898)
- [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)

  - 176 [thegreatjedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44906)
  - 110 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 96 [DVK-in-exile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976)
  - 73 [Donmax](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6239)
  - 67 [Wad Cheber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44025)
  - 58 [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693)
  - 57 [Rogue Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51226)
  - 51 [DavRob60](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45)
  - 45 [RedCaio](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54827)
  - 39 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
  - 34 [zipquincy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5912)
  - 32 [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294)
  - 27 [ThePopMachine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3823)
  - 27 [LcSalazar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/35749)
  - 24 [phantom42](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5184)
  - 24 user1027
- [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)

  - 184 [Often Right](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22917)
  - 126 [JMFB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40599)
  - 100 [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294)
  - 92 [ThePopMachine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3823)
  - 88 [trejder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7885)
  - 77 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 53 [Morgan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13090)
  - 51 user30592
  - 50 [T-1000's Son](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56162)
  - 49 [Xantec](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1234)
  - 49 [Darren](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59675)
  - 47 [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693)
  - 46 [Major Stackings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4356)
  - 41 [DVK-in-exile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976)
  - 40 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
  - 32 [The Byzantine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/9382)
  - 30 [Iszi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1639)
  - 29 [Zibbobz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20533)
  - 26 [Wikis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/143)
  - 25 [OghmaOsiris](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1109)
- [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings)

  - 84 [Wad Cheber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44025)
  - 64 [DVK-in-exile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976)
  - 57 [user31546](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40532)
  - 42 [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500)
  - 31 [Fingolfin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/53038)
  - 29 [bazz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7910)
  - 26 [user31546](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31546)
  - 26 [thegreatjedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44906)
  - 26 [Major Stackings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4356)
  - 25 [Morgan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13090)
- [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie)

  - 57 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 29 [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148)
- [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who)

  - 58 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 40 [Andrew Casali](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/63700)
  - 37 [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394)
  - 32 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
  - 24 [giacomo casanova](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21674)
- [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics)

  - 83 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
  - 54 [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056)
  - 45 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 39 [phantom42](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5184)
  - 30 [CodeMed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45944)
  - 25 [Rogue Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51226)
- [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng)

  - 71 [Often Right](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22917)
  - 50 [ThePopMachine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3823)
  - 44 [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294)
  - 43 user30592
  - 41 [JMFB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40599)
  - 39 [trejder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7885)
  - 36 [T-1000's Son](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56162)
  - 28 [Morgan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13090)
- [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien)

  - 112 [Fingolfin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/53038)
  - 95 [Wad Cheber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44025)
  - 24 [DVK-in-exile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976)
- [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe)

  - 88 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
  - 41 [CodeMed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45944)
  - 35 user1027
  - 29 [phantom42](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5184)
- [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire)

  - 31 [Leo King](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/25915)
  - 26 [Justin Ethier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5798)
- [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics)

  - 33 [OghmaOsiris](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1109)
  - 31 [Major Stackings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4356)
- [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)

  - 94 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
  - 85 [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056)
  - 27 [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693)
- [the-force-awakens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force-awakens)

  - 29 [thegreatjedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44906)
- [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv)

  - 48 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
- [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men)

  - 32 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
- [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9)

  - 60 [JMFB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40599)
  - 26 [ThePopMachine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3823)
- [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends)

  - 39 [thegreatjedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44906)
  - 32 [Rogue Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51226)
  - 28 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
- [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman)

  - 27 [Major Stackings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4356)
- [star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager)

  - 44 [JMFB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40599)
- [voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort)

  - 36 [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500)
- [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth)

  - 26 [bazz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7910)
- [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion)

  - 75 [Fingolfin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/53038)
  - 27 [Wad Cheber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44025)
- [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos)

  - 30 [Often Right](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22917)
  - 25 [JMFB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40599)
- [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)

  - 24 [DVK-in-exile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976)
- [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama)

  - 31 [Blue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5914)
- [the-walking-dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead)

  - 25 [Wad Cheber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44025)
- [magical-theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-theory)

  - 37 [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500)
- [age-of-ultron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-ultron)

  - 27 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)
- [the-clone-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-clone-wars)

  - 25 [thegreatjedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44906)
- [supernatural](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supernatural)

  - 37 [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804)
- [avatar-the-last-airbender](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender)

  - 26 [Izumi-reiLuLu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20797)
- [the-legend-of-korra](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-korra)

  - 26 [Izumi-reiLuLu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20797)
- [back-to-the-future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-to-the-future)

  - 28 [Often Right](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22917)
- [star-trek-enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-enterprise)

  - 29 [Ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931)

Comment: What does this mean, `Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the`

Comment: @KyloRen - Total score is upvotes minus downvotes.